# How to proceed with chi square test in R if one line has zeros?

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I am trying to program with R. My categorical data is in a table of 5*5. However, the 5th line has only zeros. When I run the chi square test in a software program, it returns the result INVALID. But when I delete the 5th line and assume the table to be of size 4*5, the test works.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Why does that line only have zeroes? Are these sampling zeroes or structural zeroes?

Comment: @mdewey they are structural zeroes

Comment: If the whole row consists of structural zeroes then you can just analyse the  4 by 6 table. The issue with structural zeroes is when you have just a single one somewhere in the interior of the table.

Answer (score 3):

At first, you should state whether zeros in 5th row are:

- **sampling zeros** - occure by a sheer happenstance. If you would perform more sampling you'll get more observations in each cell and ultimately also in those cells in 5th row.
- **structural zeros** - you won't ever get nonzero values in these cells, e.g. consider a contingency table desribing patients with several possible types of cancer. Let's assume rows are: Male 0-18 (Year old), Male 19-25, Male 26-40, Male 41-999 (so optimistic ;-) , probably for Methuselah),
  Female 0-18, ...., Female 41-999. Columns denote cancer types.
  So, as you probably spotted you won't ever get counts in any cell describing women at any age having prostate cancer. That are structural zeros.

By the way, the Chi Square approximation is invalid when counts are small, in which case I would recommend you Fisher's Exact Test. But even Fisher's Exact Test is **NOT** remedy for **structural zeros**.

In the case of **structural zeros** you should try completly different approach, for example logit / loglinear model. You could find theory behind it in books by Alan Agresti (*Categorical Data Analysis* or *Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis*).

Comment: thank you @Adam the zeros in my data are structural zeros...guess I will just have to use a different approach

Comment: @saritah If you're not familiar with this approach (logit/loglinear) and you don't have much time to get to know about it, I would recommend you to follow **lmo** workaround and only explain in your thesis that you're aware of that problem and that's why you perform test on table $4 \times 5$.

Comment: I am familiar with the approach but I do not know how to program it on R. If you have the code I will really appreciate

Comment: @saritah To fast start with log-linear models for contingency tables:a brief explanantion http://www.markirwin.net/stat149/Lecture/Lecture18.pdf  To do it in R, have a look on the lecture http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/312f12/lectures/312f12Loglinear1.pdf and enclosed R code: http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/312f12/lectures/312f12LoglinearWithR1.pdf   http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/312f12/lectures/312f12LoglinearWithR2.pdf   (You can delete the filename and browse the whole catalogue)

Comment: (1) The $\chi^2$ approximation can be excellent when some *counts* are small, even zero.  What you need to watch out for is the case when there is a sizable proportion of *expected* counts. (2) If there is nothing at all in the fifth row then (for the purpose of evaluating independence) you can ignore it: you don't necessarily have to take more samples.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the data to run a 5X5 test.  My advice would be to run the 4X5 test and to be honest about the missing fifth row when writing up your results.

In my experience, this is something you mention briefly in the intro, in thre results section, and discuss in some detail in the "limitations and future research" section.

Comment: @Imo thanks for the advice. I am writting my dissertation for masters and if I have to run it in a 4*5 table I have to show evidence of how I came up with the trick (as in who has ever done something like that before)